# vb.net dock two controls in order

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a picturebox and a menu strip that are both dock to top.

the menustrip is docked to the upper most part of the form and the picturebox is docked below the menu strip.

How can i make it the other way around. the picture docked to the upper most and the menu strip docked to the picture?

Comment: Can't you just right click on the picture box in desinger and 'send to back' or something like that? - I am assuming this is WinForms

Comment: In the designer (Jack's comment will do that) or at runtime with code?

Comment: Are you creating this controls during runtime.?

Comment: No. I set it on the property window.

'send to back' did the trick. Thanks guys. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your .designer.cs file. Reverse the order in which those 2 components are added to form.
If you need help with this task ask in comment.

Comment: For clarification: This changes the initial ZOrder.

Answer (score 1):

What really worked for me, was to alter de ZOrder from controls. It looks like VB uses that for setting the docking order. Try bringing controls to front and sending them to back to see its effect. Good luck!! Mariano.

Answer (score 0):

I think ,You might have `docked`(top) your controls inside that panel in the following order

- Menu Strip
- Picture Box

This is why your `controls` are not displaying as you have expected.

Just Do like this to achieve your need,

- Just Reset the `dock` property for the both controls to `none` first
- Set the `Dock` property as `Top` for that controls in this order

  1. PictureBox
  2. Menustrip

Answer (score 0):

First, set dock of two control to none then click right mouse on `Menustrip` select `Bring to Front` then click right mouse on `PictureBox` select `Bring to Back`.
Final set dock for `Menustrip` and `PictureBox`.